Controlling HTML output location in Quarto without CLI
This is a follow-up to my previous question.
In RMarkdown, I used a custom knit function to specify the output HTML file's location directly within the script. I’m looking for a similar approach in Quarto that doesn’t rely on the CLI. Is there a way to control the output location from within the Quarto script itself?

According to this Quarto contributor, there is no working way to specify an output location that isn't the current working directory as of February of this year. Some have tried using a _quarto.yml file at root, but the rendered result was not what they expected.
The Quarto dev team seems to be working on a way to accomplish this, but in the meantime using a script that can move the file to the intended location post-rendering is the only way without using the CLI.
